# PostgreSQL won't start after Windows update restarts

Tags: service, postgresql-9.3, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I have a Windows 2012R2 server with PostgreSQL 9.3.4 x64 installed as a service. It seems like everytime the server perform a Windows update and finally restart, the PostgreSQL service fail to start again. Here's the PostgreSQL log before the restart:

> LOG:  received fast shutdown request
>   LOG:  aborting any active transactions
>   FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
>   FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
>   FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
>   FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
>   FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
>   FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
>   LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
>   ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
>   LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down

After the restart I have several `postgres.exe` instances running on the server and the database folder contains a `postmaster.pid` which is not empty. The PostgreSQL log after restart contains the following:

> FATAL:  the database system is starting up
>   LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2016-04-09 02:31:22 CEST
>   LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
>   LOG:  record with zero length at D2/9C630820
>   LOG:  redo is not required
>   FATAL:  the database system is starting up
>   FATAL:  the database system is starting up
>   ...
>   FATAL:  the database system is starting up

Since the database is normally used for *readonly* purposes I guess I probably won't experience database corruption.

So far I can manually force the `postgres.exe` instances to shut down (though I have just one instance, which gives me *Access denied* when I perform an *End process* on it), delete the `postmaster.pid` file and then restart the PostgreSQL service. The service seem to start okay even though I have the rogue `postgres.exe` instance still running.

What could be the reason for Windows and PostgreSQL to struggle like this?